# Is there a reason my GPIO pins have a low voltage?

Tags: serial, screen, battery, adafruit

I'm currently using a Raspberry Pi Zero W running Pi OS Lite. I'm using the following external hats with it:

PiSugar 2 Battery 1000mAh [link](https://www.tindie.com/products/pisugar/pisugar2-battery-for-raspberry-pi-zero/)

Serial PiZero addon [link](https://thepihut.com/products/serial-pizero)

PiOLED [link](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3527)

---

Here's my situation: the battery powers the Pi from contact pins the touch the GPIO pins. The pins it uses are 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 9. The serial pi (from what I can tell) doesn't overlap these pins with the exception of power and ground. The PiOLED uses power and ground as well as I2C, utilized on pins 3 and 5. The caveat here is that the PiSugar uses those same pins and I2C to transmit battery information. Which is fine, but currently unused.

So the problem, when I boot the Pi completely assembled, GPIO pins 3 and 5 are sometimes at a much lower voltage than expected (~1.4V). When this is the case, the screen will not turn on. The serial connection still works fine as well as all other Pi services. Other times I'll turn the Pi on and those pins will read ~3.1V and the screen turns on. My question is if anyone knows the reason behind this happening. I'm open to any suggestions at this point and am able to run code on it if anyone needs more information.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the supplier?

Comment: The supplier of which part?

Comment: What have you done to pinpoint the problem?

Comment: I've looked at each piece individually and tried to figure out what causes the voltage drop to no avail. I've tried a new piece of each hat, pi, and SD card. And I've made sure they aren't working on the same I2C address. Basically, everything I could think of or find on Google

Comment: Power supply is where I would start

Comment: By default these pins are configured as INPUTs with 1.8kΩ pullup.

Depends on what is connected and how they are configured.

Comment: Your question is a ball of confusion. Buy a voltmeter, take some measurements, break the problem down into smaller pieces.

Comment: I have. When the Pi Zero is only connected to the battery, it will sometimes read ~1.4V and other times will read ~3.1V. When it does read 3.1V, I put the serial hat on it. Normally, the voltage will stay the same. Finally, I add the PiOLED. Again, sometimes it runs at 3.3V and the screen turns on just fine. Other times it will drop to 1.4V and stop working. I've replaced every part and had the same behavior